Quantum mechanical model of a system together with its measurement device
I am reading Griffith's introduction to quantum mechanics. The book assumes an object quantum system and then assumes that we somehow perform a measurement on it from the outside.
However, clearly the combined system that includes the object system and the measurement device should itself satisfy the Schrödinger equation. Is there a standard model of a simple system (e.g. a harmonic oscillator) together with a measurement device which somehow measures the energy of the oscillator?

Two qubits and a CNOT gate is the simplest and most rudimentary example (here's a picture, qubit $|a\rangle$ to be observed, and $|b\rangle$ should be an ancilla qubit, prepared for instane in state $|0\rangle$. https://i.sstatic.net/9XnqqzKN.png )

YES, its a whole area called decoherence theory.

A simple model for the interaction between a system $S$ and measurement device $M$ for any system can be described by the following.
Consider an observable $\hat O_S$ defined on the system, and consider the momentum operator $\hat P_M$ of the measurement device. The momentum operator generates displacements (in position) of the "meter" of the measurement device in the sense that
$$
e^{-i\hat P_M x}|a \rangle = |a+x\rangle.
$$
You can think if it as giving a "kick" to the meter that moves it to the appropriate value.
Then consider the unitary operator
$$
\hat U_{SM} \equiv e^{-i\hat O_S\otimes \hat P_M }
$$
over the tensor product Hilbert space $\mathcal H_S \otimes\mathcal H_M$. When this unitary acts on an initial state that is a tensor product of an eigen state $|\psi_j\rangle$ of $\hat O_M$ with eigen value $o_j$ and the $|0\rangle$ state of the meter we have:
$$
e^{-i\hat O_S\otimes \hat P_M }|\psi_j\rangle|0\rangle = |\psi_j\rangle e^{-i\hat P_Mo_j }|0\rangle  = |\psi_j\rangle |o_j\rangle 
$$
where the key step was being able to replace $\hat O_S$ with its eigenvalue $o_j$.
Now in the general case the input state on the system will be in a super position of many eigen states of $\hat O_S$, that is $|\Psi\rangle = \sum_j c_j |\psi_j\rangle$. By linearity we then have:
$$
e^{-i\hat O_S\otimes \hat P_M }|\Psi\rangle|0\rangle = \sum_j c_j |\psi_j\rangle |o_j\rangle 
$$
where the meter is now in an entangled superposition with the system.

There is a large literature on modelling measurement in quantum theory. A measurement is an interaction that produces a record that can be copied. If a quantum system is undergoing interference and a record is made of its state the interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832
https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0149
In everyday life all of the objects you see around you are constantly undergoing measurement like interactions that copy information about them, e.g. - the light reflecting off the computer I'm typing this on, sound from the keys being carried away in changes of pressure in air, the computer exerting pressure on a desktop and so on. As a result on the scales of space and time in everyday life interference is suppressed for every object you see.
In experiments in a lab you can control interactions more precisely and measure and control decoherence to some extent. For a review with many references to experiments, including molecules, nanomechanical resonators and many other kinds of systems:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09755
